# Can you run multiple ISR's simultaneously without threading?

Tags: c++, embedded, arduino-uno

I have been dissecting some code used to control multiple stepper motors at once using a compare timer interrupt  but the way the code is written I cannot tell if the code is actually triggering separate interrupts to be run simultaneously or if it is stepping the motors one step at a time and cycling through each motor as a loop until they have all reached the desired position. My main question is since they are using the same output compare register to trigger the next interrupt there cannot be multiple isr's since they cannot but different values in the same memory location correct? And if so is my assumption that it is stepping the motors one at a time correct?

````
  #define X_DIR_PIN          55
  #define X_STEP_PIN         54
  #define X_ENABLE_PIN       38

  #define Y_DIR_PIN          61
  #define Y_STEP_PIN         60
  #define Y_ENABLE_PIN       56

  #define Z_DIR_PIN          48
  #define Z_STEP_PIN         46
  #define Z_ENABLE_PIN       62

  #define A_DIR_PIN          28
  #define A_STEP_PIN         26
  #define A_ENABLE_PIN       24

  #define B_DIR_PIN          34
  #define B_STEP_PIN         36
  #define B_ENABLE_PIN       30

#define C_DIR_PIN          32
#define C_STEP_PIN         47
#define C_ENABLE_PIN       45

#define X_STEP_HIGH             PORTF |=  0b00000001;
#define X_STEP_LOW              PORTF &= ~0b00000001;

#define Y_STEP_HIGH             PORTF |=  0b01000000;
#define Y_STEP_LOW              PORTF &= ~0b01000000;

#define Z_STEP_HIGH             PORTL |=  0b00001000;
#define Z_STEP_LOW              PORTL &= ~0b00001000;

#define A_STEP_HIGH             PORTA |=  0b00010000;
#define A_STEP_LOW              PORTA &= ~0b00010000;

#define B_STEP_HIGH             PORTC |=  0b00000010;
#define B_STEP_LOW              PORTC &= ~0b00000010;

#define C_STEP_HIGH             PORTL |=  0b00000100;
#define C_STEP_LOW              PORTL &= ~0b00000100;

#define TIMER1_INTERRUPTS_ON    TIMSK1 |=  (1 << OCIE1A);
#define TIMER1_INTERRUPTS_OFF   TIMSK1 &= ~(1 << OCIE1A);

struct stepperInfo {
  // externally defined parameters
  float acceleration;
  volatile unsigned int minStepInterval;   // ie. max speed, smaller is faster
  void (*dirFunc)(int);
  void (*stepFunc)();

  // derived parameters
  unsigned int c0;                // step interval for first step, determines acceleration
  long stepPosition;              // current position of stepper (total of all movements taken so far)

  // per movement variables (only changed once per movement)
  volatile int dir;                        // current direction of movement, used to keep track of position
  volatile unsigned int totalSteps;        // number of steps requested for current movement
  volatile bool movementDone = false;      // true if the current movement has been completed (used by main program to wait for completion)
  volatile unsigned int rampUpStepCount;   // number of steps taken to reach either max speed, or half-way to the goal (will be zero until this number is known)

  // per iteration variables (potentially changed every interrupt)
  volatile unsigned int n;                 // index in acceleration curve, used to calculate next interval
  volatile float d;                        // current interval length
  volatile unsigned long di;               // above variable truncated
  volatile unsigned int stepCount;         // number of steps completed in current movement
};

void xStep() {
  X_STEP_HIGH
  X_STEP_LOW
}
void xDir(int dir) {
  digitalWrite(X_DIR_PIN, dir);
}

void yStep() {
  Y_STEP_HIGH
  Y_STEP_LOW
}
void yDir(int dir) {
  digitalWrite(Y_DIR_PIN, dir);
}

void zStep() {
  Z_STEP_HIGH
  Z_STEP_LOW
}
void zDir(int dir) {
  digitalWrite(Z_DIR_PIN, dir);
}

void aStep() {
  A_STEP_HIGH
  A_STEP_LOW
}
void aDir(int dir) {
  digitalWrite(A_DIR_PIN, dir);
}

void bStep() {
  B_STEP_HIGH
  B_STEP_LOW
}
void bDir(int dir) {
  digitalWrite(B_DIR_PIN, dir);
}

void cStep() {
  C_STEP_HIGH
  C_STEP_LOW
}
void cDir(int dir) {
  digitalWrite(C_DIR_PIN, dir);
}

void resetStepperInfo( stepperInfo& si ) {
  si.n = 0;
  si.d = 0;
  si.di = 0;
  si.stepCount = 0;
  si.rampUpStepCount = 0;
  si.totalSteps = 0;
  si.stepPosition = 0;
  si.movementDone = false;
}

#define NUM_STEPPERS 6

volatile stepperInfo steppers[NUM_STEPPERS];

void setup() {

  pinMode(X_STEP_PIN,   OUTPUT);
  pinMode(X_DIR_PIN,    OUTPUT);
  pinMode(X_ENABLE_PIN, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(Y_STEP_PIN,   OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Y_DIR_PIN,    OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Y_ENABLE_PIN, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(Z_STEP_PIN,   OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Z_DIR_PIN,    OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Z_ENABLE_PIN, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(A_STEP_PIN,   OUTPUT);
  pinMode(A_DIR_PIN,    OUTPUT);
  pinMode(A_ENABLE_PIN, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(B_STEP_PIN,   OUTPUT);
  pinMode(B_DIR_PIN,    OUTPUT);
  pinMode(B_ENABLE_PIN, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(C_STEP_PIN,   OUTPUT);
  pinMode(C_DIR_PIN,    OUTPUT);
  pinMode(C_ENABLE_PIN, OUTPUT);

  digitalWrite(X_ENABLE_PIN, LOW);
  digitalWrite(Y_ENABLE_PIN, LOW);
  digitalWrite(Z_ENABLE_PIN, LOW);
  digitalWrite(A_ENABLE_PIN, LOW);
  digitalWrite(B_ENABLE_PIN, LOW);
  digitalWrite(C_ENABLE_PIN, LOW);

  noInterrupts();
  TCCR1A = 0;
  TCCR1B = 0;
  TCNT1  = 0;

  OCR1A = 1000;                             // compare value
  TCCR1B |= (1 << WGM12);                   // CTC mode
  TCCR1B |= ((1 << CS11) | (1 << CS10));    // 64 prescaler
  interrupts();

  steppers[0].dirFunc = bDir;
  steppers[0].stepFunc = bStep;
  steppers[0].acceleration = 1000;
  steppers[0].minStepInterval = 50;

  steppers[1].dirFunc = aDir;
  steppers[1].stepFunc = aStep;
  steppers[1].acceleration = 4000;
  steppers[1].minStepInterval = 50;

  steppers[2].dirFunc = cDir;
  steppers[2].stepFunc = cStep;
  steppers[2].acceleration = 1000;
  steppers[2].minStepInterval = 50;

  steppers[3].dirFunc = xDir;
  steppers[3].stepFunc = xStep;
  steppers[3].acceleration = 1000;
  steppers[3].minStepInterval = 250;

  steppers[4].dirFunc = yDir;
  steppers[4].stepFunc = yStep;
  steppers[4].acceleration = 1000;
  steppers[4].minStepInterval = 50;

  steppers[5].dirFunc = zDir;
  steppers[5].stepFunc = zStep;
  steppers[5].acceleration = 1000;
  steppers[5].minStepInterval = 450;
}

void resetStepper(volatile stepperInfo& si) {
  si.c0 = si.acceleration;
  si.d = si.c0;
  si.di = si.d;
  si.stepCount = 0;
  si.n = 0;
  si.rampUpStepCount = 0;
  si.movementDone = false;
}

volatile byte remainingSteppersFlag = 0;

void prepareMovement(int whichMotor, int steps) {
  volatile stepperInfo& si = steppers[whichMotor];
  si.dirFunc( steps < 0 ? HIGH : LOW );
  si.dir = steps > 0 ? 1 : -1;
  si.totalSteps = abs(steps);
  resetStepper(si);
  remainingSteppersFlag |= (1 << whichMotor);
}

volatile byte nextStepperFlag = 0;

volatile int ind = 0;
volatile unsigned int intervals[100];

void setNextInterruptInterval() {

  bool movementComplete = true;

  unsigned int mind = 999999;
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_STEPPERS; i++) {
    if ( ((1 << i) & remainingSteppersFlag) && steppers[i].di < mind ) {
      mind = steppers[i].di;
    }
  }

  nextStepperFlag = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_STEPPERS; i++) {
    if ( ! steppers[i].movementDone )
      movementComplete = false;

    if ( ((1 << i) & remainingSteppersFlag) && steppers[i].di == mind )
      nextStepperFlag |= (1 << i);
  }

  if ( remainingSteppersFlag == 0 ) {
    OCR1A = 65500;
  }

  OCR1A = mind;
}

ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect)
{
  unsigned int tmpCtr = OCR1A;

  OCR1A = 65500;

  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_STEPPERS; i++) {

    if ( ! ((1 << i) & remainingSteppersFlag) )
      continue;

    if ( ! (nextStepperFlag & (1 << i)) ) {
      steppers[i].di -= tmpCtr;
      continue;
    }

    volatile stepperInfo& s = steppers[i];

    if ( s.stepCount < s.totalSteps ) {
      s.stepFunc();
      s.stepCount++;
      s.stepPosition += s.dir;
      if ( s.stepCount >= s.totalSteps ) {
        s.movementDone = true;
        remainingSteppersFlag &= ~(1 << i);
      }
    }

    if ( s.rampUpStepCount == 0 ) {
      s.n++;
      s.d = s.d - (2 * s.d) / (4 * s.n + 1);
      if ( s.d <= s.minStepInterval ) {
        s.d = s.minStepInterval;
        s.rampUpStepCount = s.stepCount;
      }
      if ( s.stepCount >= s.totalSteps / 2 ) {
        s.rampUpStepCount = s.stepCount;
      }
    }
    else if ( s.stepCount >= s.totalSteps - s.rampUpStepCount ) {
      s.d = (s.d * (4 * s.n + 1)) / (4 * s.n + 1 - 2);
      s.n--;
    }

    s.di = s.d; // integer
  }

  setNextInterruptInterval();

  TCNT1  = 0;
}

void runAndWait() {
  setNextInterruptInterval();
  while ( remainingSteppersFlag );
}

void loop() {

  TIMER1_INTERRUPTS_ON

  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < NUM_STEPPERS; k++) {
      prepareMovement( k,  200 );
      runAndWait();
    }
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < NUM_STEPPERS; k++) {
      prepareMovement( k,  200 );
    }
    runAndWait();
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_STEPPERS; i++)
    prepareMovement( i, 400 );
  runAndWait();
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_STEPPERS; i++)
    prepareMovement( i, -400 );
  runAndWait();
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_STEPPERS; i++)
    prepareMovement( i, 200 );
  runAndWait();
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_STEPPERS; i++)
    prepareMovement( i, -200 );
  runAndWait();
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_STEPPERS; i++)
    prepareMovement( i, 600 );
  runAndWait();
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_STEPPERS; i++)
    prepareMovement( i, -600 );
  runAndWait();

  while (true);

}```
````

Comment: There are alternatives to threads, sure. You can write a single-threaded state machine. You can use multiple processes. Threads serve a purpose, but they are not the only possible solution.

Comment: In my decades of embedded systems experience, processors only like to run one ISR at a time.  Some ISRs can interrupt other ISRs, while others will wait for the present one to finish. I have yet to see a processor run multiple ISRs *simultaneously*.

Comment: Usually, you set up a stepper motor to be polled or interrupted.  Smart stepper motors can trigger an interrupt when they have finished a "step" or completed multiple "steps".  A step is triggered either through a write (via register) or by pulsing (a.k.a. PWM).  You could set up a thread to perform the PWM, but consider what happens when the thread is swapped out.

Comment: You do realize that when there is only one CPU, "simultaneously" is an illusion!

Comment: "Can you run multiple ISR's simultaneously without threading?" That question doesn't make any sense. Threads are a higher level concept, which is based on context switching, which in turn is based of low-level interrupts.

Comment: @tonypdmtr There's DMA, but probably not on old stuff like AVR.

Comment: You appear to have conflated two different issues: The first the conceptual issue in the title, and second the "how does this code work?" question in the body. Since the concept in the title makes little sense, it certainly does not relate to how the code works.

Comment: @tonypdmtr : There is true concurrency in this case in the sense that after the step pulse is issued the motor will continue to move to the next one-step position _concurrently_ to the CPU running. In the time it takes the motor to complete the step, the processor can do other work.  In this case critically it sends the step pulse for each motor without waiting having for each Motors step to complete - the motion is concurrent.

Comment: @Clifford Right for the motors, but that's not same as multiple ISRs executing simultaneously.  So, it's still 'no'.

Comment: @tonypdmtr For sure.  I was only referring to your comment, not the question.  The question in the title is in any case an X-Y problem.  He has some code he does not understand, has come up with a hypothesis of how it works, then asking whether the hypothesis is plausible (it's not).  Better perhaps to explain how the code does in fact work than to simply say "no".

Answer (score 2):

I'd strongly recommend to study basic assembler when doing MCU programming.

The basics of interrupts is that upon entering an ISR, a typical MCU sets a global interrupt mask automatically. The AVR is no exception - it is derived from the "Motorola school" of things where the global interrupt mask is called `I` and stored in the *condition code register* - AVR calls this one [`STATUS`](https://microchipdeveloper.com/8avr:status). This is the most important register in the whole MCU since apart from interrupt handling, all results of executed instructions are reported here too.

The `STATUS` register will be automatically saved on the stack whenever an ISR is fired, so that on-going calculations may continue where they were after the ISR is done executing. Once the register is saved, the MCU automatically clears the `I` bit and blocks all other interrupts from triggering.

`I` can also be set manually with `SEI` or `CLI` instructions. Doing this from inside an ISR would mean that you let pending interrupts in, possibly of the same kind as you were already executing. Note that each interrupt uses it's own stack space, so it is in theory possibly to execute half of the ISR, then let another interrupt in, freeze execution and have that other interrupt execute instead. It works like recursion.

Even with the global interrupt mask enabled, the hardware that triggers interrupts may still set the flags that would trigger an interrupt. This means that as soon as your ISR is done executing and the interrupt mask is disabled, other pending interrupts may execute immediately. This is done according to some interrupt priority schedule specified by the MCU manufacturer and/or programmer. But you cannot execute multiple interrupts simultaneously.

In case of PWM specifically, there can however be one single interrupt that marks the start of a the duty cycle, in cases where multiple PWM channels are running simultaneously.

Regarding modifying shared memory from interrupts, that's a whole different story. I'd recommend reading [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/409570/6102).

Comment: `Meaning I=0 means interrupts disabled on AVR, but it means interrupts disabled on Motorola school` I think one should be "enabled"?

Comment: @KamilCuk Typo - I removed that part since it's not really related to the question anyway.

Comment: @KamilCuk Most Motorola parts I've worked with use I=0 for enabled

Comment: @tonypdmtr Yes it should be I=1 for enabled on AVR, I=0 for enabled on Motorola. Consequently, `CLI`/`SEI` do the opposite on these two ISAs. The instruction set on AVR is otherwise very similar to the 6800/68HC*.

Answer (score 1):

> My main question is [...] there cannot be multiple isr's  [...]?

Your code clearly shows just *one* ISR. If an ISR is called, its interrupt is disabled until it returns.

The ISR could enable its interrupt, though, but I see no instruction for this in your code. I did this rarely and on other microcontrollers, but it is definitively possible and leads to recursive calls of the *same* ISR. I'm not sure about the AVR, though.

Actually the interrupt is bound to a fixed address for its ISR. There can only be *one* ISR for each interrupt. (Set aside some clever tricks like i.e. memory banking or jump vectors in RAM.)

> And if so is my assumption that it is stepping the motors one at a time correct?

Without going deeper into your source, it looks to me as if at each run of the ISR those motors are stepped whose "time has come." Look into `steppers[*].di`, for example.

With the knowledge that the ISR is run on its own as a whole, you could investigate the source and follow its flow.

Presumably the ISR is called whenever it is time to produce the next step, for each motor that has to be stepped at that time. Think about two motors running at 100 Hz and 200 Hz, respectively. The ISR will be called at 200 Hz, but the first motor will be stepped only every second call.

So the answer is rather:

"From the outside, all motors are stepped in parallel, each at its own speed."

Answer (score 1):

The `loop()` sets a target relative position for each motor, then waits until all motors have reached their target position.  Performing a sequence of such steps.

On each timer interrupt, for each motor that has not yet reached its target, a step pulse is generated. (In fact it is a little more complicated, since each motor has speed and acceleration profiles, so the step pulse is generated when demanded by the motion profile).

An important thing to note is that the step pulse is very short, the motor controller generates the correct signals to the motor coils to complete the step. The step pulse is completed long before the motor reaches the end of the step (or even starts its step), so although the pulses for each motor are issued sequentially, because this takes no significant time compared to the step time, all motors can step *simultaneously* not sequentially.

So there are two threads of execution - the timer ISR and the `loop()`.  The ISR allows the stepping to occur asynchronously to the `loop()` code, which can then do other work.  Except in this case it does nothing other than wait for the steps to complete, which rather negates any benefit of background stepping - turning the asynchronous motion into a completely synchronous process.

Regardless of the merits and deficiencies of the Arduino Sketch `setup()`/`loop()` framework, this particular implementation defeats it completely by never iterating `loop()` and blocking indefinitely at its end. The framework expects `loop()` to run to completion and it calls it repeatedly (hence its name - it is the body of the executive loop).

The `loop()` body should be implemented as a non-blocking state-machine or sequence of state machines, for example:

```
void runNoWait() 
{
    setNextInterruptInterval();
}

void loop()
{
    static const int sequence[] = { 200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,
                                    400,-400,200,-200,600,-600} ;
    static const sequence_steps = sizeof(sequence) / sizeof(*sequence) ;

    static sequence_index = 0 ;

    // If sequence not complete...
    if( sequence_index <  sequence_steps )
    { 
        // If all motor positions achieved...
        if( remainingSteppersFlag == 0x00 )
        {
            // For each motor set up next position
            for( int k = 0; k < NUM_STEPPERS; k++) 
            {
                prepareMovement( k, sequence[sequence_index] ) ;
            }

            // Start motors
            runNoWait() ;

            // Next step in sequence
            sequence_index++ ;
        }
    }

    // Do other (non-blocking) stuff here while 
    // simultaneously executing motor sequence
    ...
}
```

This will allow you to make effective use of the CPU, getting more work done and and allowing more responsive behaviour.  For example you could poll an emergency stop input to abort the motion:

```
void allStop()
{
    remainingSteppersFlag = 0 ;
} 

void loop()
{
    ...

    // Stop sequence immediately on button press
    if( digitalRead(buttonPin) == LOW )
    {
        allStop() ;
        sequence_index = sequence_steps ;
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: OK I understand better after reading your answer thanks, I had the general understanding but this code was confusing and making me question certain things, as for why the use of interrupts the intent is to use the isr so I can poll for serial commands from a users or myself , as it is now it will only run predetermined and I wanted the main loop to be able to handle more than just motion commands like current location so I thought the isr would be good to allow motors to run in the background.

Comment: @MacLCM You are welcome, but note that SO is not a discussion forum.  No need to comment on how an answer may have helped or what you intend to do with the information.  Instead SO encourages voting (up or down) and "accepting".